# random status help, changing to watching

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I made a random status for my bot, the problem is I want to change it so it says "watching" and not playing.

```
const actvs = [`Watching ${client.guilds.size}`, "with the developers console", "with some code",
"with someone"];

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity(actvs[Math.floor(Math.random() * (actvs.length - 1) + 1)]);
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity(actvs[Math.floor(Math.random() * (actvs.length - 1) + 1)]);
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`client.guilds.size` isn't defined before the ready event, and you don't need to add and subtract one in the randomizer.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    const actvs = [`Watching ${client.guilds.size}`, "with the developers console", "with some code","with someone"];
    client.user.setActivity(actvs[Math.floor(Math.random() * (actvs.length)]);
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity(actvs[Math.floor(Math.random() * (actvs.length)]);
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ClientUser#setActivity()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) has a default type of `PLAYING`. You can override this behavior in the second parameter of the function.

```js
client.user.setActivity('...', { type: 'WATCHING' });
```

---

Also, [`client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) won't be populated outside of the [`ready`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) event, and if you're using [`v12.x`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/updating), [`client.guilds.size`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Collection?scrollTo=size) should be [`client.guilds.cache.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size)

Lastly, adding and subtracting one in the randomizer will make it impossible to pick the first two elements, and possible to pick an element that doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

```js
client.user.setActivity(actvs[Math.floor(Math.random() * (actvs.length - 1) + 1)], {
   type: "WATCHING"
})
```

Comment: @HiHiGetYEET091, that is not helpful. What is not working? What errors do you get? What is your code? My code is the correct code, and it worked for me.